# Clone PC drive to Mac and back to PC

Tags: windows, mac, hard-drive, clone

I am in the process of swapping a HDD from a PC (containing two partitions, one with Windows XP and the other with Ubuntu) with the HD from a MacBook Pro (containing some partitions, but I can take care of the Mac with another Mac that I have).

First, I want to clone/save the two PC partitions, so that when I replace the HD (from the Mac to the PC) I can restore it to the old Mac HD that goes into the PC.

My question/desired technique is

1. is there a way to clone the PC HD to the Mac
   (will Carbon Copy Cloner do that?, maybe via target disc mode? I don't know if it will recognize the HD without reformatting.)
2. and then put the original Mac HDD into the MacBook Pro (just for the task of restoring to the HDD that will go to the PC), restore it (and then taking it to the PC with the files restored onto the "new" HDD).
3. In the end, I will then place the original PC HDD into the Mac and restore my Mac files, but that's another story.

Unless I'm over-complicating this, and I can do this without using the Mac as a container for the PC HDD restoration? (I don't have any other Windows machines, although I have parallels).

(I searched and couldn't find a suitable answer to this problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Clone Windows HDD on Apple Mac OS X machine](http://rolfje.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/clone-windows-hd-on-apple-osx-machine/)* may help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: Although this answer didn't have details (and the link had), I'll approve it, since `dd` was the *perfect* method for my question, thanks!